# Validating a hashed password in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a custom system that works in parallell with my wordpress site, and the idea is that one can login to this system with the same credentials (username and password) as the ones they've made on my wordpress site.

So I already have a custom login-page for this system which, on submission, checks if the entered username and password exists in the wordpress database.

I've managed to do this, but it seems to generate a new string everytime it's run:

```
include_once( "../wp-config.php" );
include_once( "../wp-includes/class-phpass.php" );

    $password = mysql_escape_string("password123");
    $wp_hash = new PasswordHash( 8, TRUE );
    echo $wp_hash->HashPassword( $password );
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

if ( $user && wp_check_password( $pass, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
  echo "That's it";
else
  echo "Nope";
```

you can see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password)

and if you define password's hash in your code;

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-load.php");
$password = '123456';
$hash = '$P$BpR40ssU1UobqMELuNlwzxVa4XgKNk1';
var_dump(wp_check_password($password, $hash));
```

note that be careful because you should define your password hash.

You can generate wordress pass hasher from [here](http://scriptserver.mainframe8.com/wordpress_password_hasher.php)